# Disable padding in material ui card

Tags: css, material-ui

I'm using a card from material UI and when I inspect the card I have this class :

"MulticardContent-root" which gives me padding 16, how do I remove it? its not in the styles component.

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite using following css.

```
.MuiCardContent-root {
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

And if you want for specific page only then dont forget to add one parent class.

```
.test .MuiCardContent-root {
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried that actually, but it doesn't seem to overwrite the material ui styles.

Comment: try adding !important == padding: 0px !important;.